# Azure bicep store App Ip in string parameter

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-bicep

I would like to store the outbound ip of an App site in a string parameter, so I could use it later to split the ips into an array, but I get the "this symbol cannot be referenced here. only other parameters can be referenced in parameter default values" message and I do not how to proceed

Can anyone help me? Here is my code:

```
resource sitewww 'Microsoft.Web/sites@2022-03-01' = {

name: 'sitewwwname'
location: 'westeurope'

}

param variable string = sitewww.properties.outboundIpAddresses
param allowedIpAddresses array = split(variable,',')
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: you can use`'[reference(resourceId(''Microsoft.Web/sites'', ''sitewwwname''), ''2022-03-01'').properties.outboundIpAddresses]'` in param variable string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to be using a variables here not a parameters.

So the param declarations below your resource would change to var

So your bicep above would be

```
resource sitewww 'Microsoft.Web/sites@2022-03-01' = {

name: 'sitewwwname'
location: 'westeurope'

}

var variable = sitewww.properties.outboundIpAddresses
var allowedIpAddresses = split(variable,',')
```